# How to set the dropdown width for multi select listbox mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listbox, multi-select

here is my listbox editor template

```
@if (ViewData[fieldId + "_list"] is   System.Collections.IEnumerable)
   { 
    @Html.ListBox("", new MultiSelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData[fieldId + "_list"], "Value", "Name", Model),
    new { @style = "margin:0px; width:225px;", @class = "multi-select", multiple = "multiple", data_placeholder = " " })
   }
   else
    { 
@Html.ListBox("", new MultiSelectList(new List<SingleValueHolder<int>>(), Model),
    new { @style = "margin:0px; width:225px;", @class = "multi-select", multiple = "multiple", data_placeholder = " " })}
```

if we set the width here the whole listbox width is set.

Comment: So what are you expecting from what you wrote?

Comment: From the above the listbox works fine, the items are wrapped if the width is too long. If want to just change the dropdown width not the actual width of the control. Is there anyway to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two listbox one with desired width, another which holds the value.
then use the magic z- index to hide the one with big drop down

see this **[LINK TO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/m4wpgr6a/)**

```
<div> <span> <select readonly='readonly' id='sel' name="sometext" style = "width:55px;position: absolute; z-index: -1">
    <option>text1</option>
    <option>text2</option>
    <option>text3</option> 
    <option >some very long text </option>         
</select>
   <div  style="width:500px;height:25px ;background-color:white; z-index: 10" >
       <div id="ddiv" tyle="width:500px;height:25px ;background-color:white; z-index: 15" />
       <select id='dummy' style = "width:65px;position: absolute; z-index: 10">
             <option style="display:none">text1</option>
    <option style="display:none">text2</option>
    <option style="display:none">text3</option>
            <option style="display:none">some very long text </option>  
       </select>
       </div>
   </span>
</div>
```

and in javascript

```
$('#sel').change(function () {
$('#dummy').val($('#sel').val());
});

$('#ddiv').click(function () {
open($('#sel'));
}
);

function open(elem) {
if (document.createEvent) {
    var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    elem[0].dispatchEvent(e);
} else if (element.fireEvent) {
    elem[0].fireEvent("onmousedown");
}
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, I dont know how to implement in my application

Comment: Hi you can use the same logic to follow in your application, u will be defining additional drop down box for which will act as a dummy. In the above answer the dummy drop down is visible, on click of dummy the  original drop down to selected. the dropdowns are stacked on top of each other

Answer (score -1):

I think you are setting the html attributes of whole List box i.e:@html.Listbox.
so in result you will get the width for the same.